# Issues with export type in Create React App (CRA)

Tags: typescript, webpack, create-react-app

i want to upgrade react-scripts from 4.0.3 to 5.0.0.
typescript version is 4.2.4

After upgrading I get a lot of issues like this:

```
export 'InterfaceA' (reexported as 'InterfaceA') was not found in './abc/t' (possible exports: YYYY, __esModule)
```

even though InterfaceA is there. I tried to fix it with using `export type` on the reexport, as i read that is way to fix the error.

Unfortunately, after this I get the following error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:7)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| export { ApiConfiguration, RefreshStrategy } from './src/api/interfaces';
| //Auth
> export type {
```

It seems it cannot handle the export type it wanted... what do i do now?

Comment: People can't help you with code they can't see. Please include a [mre] of the definitions, exports, and imports you're having trouble with in the question.